# subscribe API from MongoDB error after change route

Tags: angular, express, mongoose

I create a service to get data from MongoDB API. At first, it works fine. But when I change to another route and comeback. It becomes undefined. I click the browser refresh and it comes back to normal.

product.service.ts:

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, catchError, retry, throwError, map } from 'rxjs';
    import { Product } from '../interface/product';
    
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class productAPIService {
    
        constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
    
        getProducts(category: string): Observable<any> {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8")
            const requestOptions: Object = {
                headers: headers,
                responseType: "text"
            }
            return this._http.get<any>("http://localhost:3002/" + category, requestOptions).pipe(
                map(res => JSON.parse(res) as Array<Product>),
                retry(3),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            )
        }
        
        track_products(category: string){
            let products_lst: any;
            this.getProducts(category).subscribe(res => {
                products_lst = res;
            });
            return products_lst;
        }
    
        handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
            return throwError(() => new Error(error.message))
        }
    
    }
```

product-list.component.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { productAPIService } from '../../services/product.service';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgxPaginationModule],
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product-list.component.css'
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  p: number = 1;
  all_products: any = [];
  daychuyen_products: any = [];
  nhan_products: any = [];
  vongtay_products: any = [];
  bongtai_products: any = [];
  fil_products: any = [];

  constructor(private _service: productAPIService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.daychuyen_products = this._service.track_products("daychuyen");
    this.nhan_products = this._service.track_products("nhan");
    this.vongtay_products = this._service.track_products("vongtay");
    this.bongtai_products = this._service.track_products("bongtai");

    this.all_products = [].concat(this.bongtai_products, this.nhan_products, this. vongtay_products, this.daychuyen_products).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    this.fil_products = this.all_products;
    console.log(this.fil_products);
  }

  filledStars(num: number) {
    return Array(num).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1);
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {}
}
```

When `ng serve` the fist time, worked as expected:
[image]

Go to another route and return to product-list component route:
[image]

Can anyone explain this for me. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Ya quite a weird behavior. But in your HTML, you can do the prevention like optional chaining (`?.`), `*ngIf` to handle the variable/property when it is `undefined`.

Comment: @YongShun so it means my component will not always show output?? :((((

Answer (score 0):

When your app starts, it probably takes some time to render the html. If the service you have build is quicker with picking up the data, it will show it all correctly in your html as the products array is not undefined.

Try putting "?." on line 127 in your product-list.component.html, just before you call images there. This should let the rendering engine know that the value at first draw of the page can be undefined. Angular will handle the incoming update and draw all your data on the screen when your asynchronous request has completed.